# Where is JConsole in Leopard

Tags: java, macos, osx-leopard, jconsole

does anyone knows where JConsole is Located in MacOSX (Leopard)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Java 6? `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home/bin/jconsole`

Java 5? `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Home/bin/jconsole`

If you want to find any program or file located on your Mac OS X 10.5 system, you can go to terminal and do it the unix way:

Either:

```
locate jconsole
```

Or:

```
find / -name jconsole
```

I prefer the first one 'cause it's faster. It uses a prebuilt index to perform the search.

Comment: should be based on where java is installed. (I install java by use jenv, so the path is `~/.jenv/versions/oracle64-9.0.1/bin/jconsole`